# Método para inverter uma Lista Encadeada Simples

Tags: java, lista

Como fazer o método `ImprimirLista()` imprimir a lista invertida.

```
Exemplo [1][2][3]
Imprimir [3][2][1]
```

**Edit 1**
Não posso usar Collections

```
public class ListaEncadeada {
    No primeiro,ultimo;
    int totalNos;

    public ListaEncadeada(){
        primeiro = ultimo = null;
        totalNos = 0;
    }

    public int getTotalNos(){
        return totalNos;
    }



    public boolean checkIfListaVazia(){
        if (getTotalNos() == 0){
            return true;
       }
       return false;
    }

    public void inserirNoInicio(No n) {
        if ( checkIfListaVazia() ){
            primeiro = ultimo = n;
        }
        else{
            n.prox = primeiro;
            primeiro = n;
        }
        totalNos++;
    }

    public void inserirNoFim(No n){
        // caso não existam nós inseridos,
        // insere o primeiro nó (n) na lista
        if ( checkIfListaVazia() ){
            primeiro = ultimo = n;
        }
        else{
            ultimo.prox = n;
            ultimo = n;
       }
       totalNos++;
    }

    public void excluirNo(No n){
        No noAtual;
        No noAnterior;
        noAtual = noAnterior = primeiro;
        int contador = 1;

        if (checkIfListaVazia() == false){
            while (contador <= getTotalNos() &&
                     noAtual.valor != n.valor){
                noAnterior = noAtual;
                noAtual = noAtual.prox;
                contador++;
            } 

        if(noAtual.valor == n.valor){
            if ( getTotalNos() == 1){
                primeiro = ultimo = null;
           }
           else{
               if (noAtual == primeiro){
                   primeiro = noAtual.prox;
               }
               else{
                   noAnterior.prox = noAtual.prox;
               }
           }
           totalNos--;
        }
    }
}

public void exibirLista(){
    No temp = ultimo;
    String valores = "";
    int contador = 1;
    if ( checkIfListaVazia() == false ){
        while (contador <= getTotalNos()){
            valores += Integer.toString(temp.valor)+"-";
            temp = temp.prox;
            contador++;
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, valores);
 }


}
```

Comment: É uma lista simplesmente ligada ou duplamente ligada ? Tem como colocar a classe `No` que você esta a utilizar ?

Comment: Acredito que [este link](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=curso+gratis+estrutura+de+dados&oq=curso+gratis+estrutura+de+dados&aqs=chrome..69i57.8030j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) vai te ajudar hehe

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma simples que tem de o fazer sem utilizar estruturas auxiliares ou alterar para uma lista duplamente ligada é com recursão.

Pode ir abrindo cada nó seguinte até chegar ao fim, o `NULL` e antes de terminar a função, imprime o nó. É a mesma lógica de imprimir uma `String` ao contrário com recursividade.

Exemplo:

```
public void imprimirLista(){
    imprimirAuxiliar(primeiro);
}

private void imprimirAuxiliar(No no){
    if (no == null){
        return;
    }

    imprimirAuxiliar(no.prox);
    System.out.print("[" + no.valor + "]");
}
```

Comment: Olá @Isac vi que você comentou lista duplamente ligada. No caso uma simples como você faria a inversão?

Comment: @YODA Nesse caso é diferente a lógica que precisa é outra. E vale ressaltar que este código não inverte a lista, apenas **mostra a lista invertida**.